# My email is undeliverable for Google Groups. How Can I fix it?

Tags: google-groups

I am an owner and administrator of some mailing groups on Google Groups. I have noticed that I do not receive all emails from these groups, some messages are lost. My email address appeared in the list of undeliverable addresses in Google Groups administration. This list doesn't show any details about the issue. I asked my web hosting service to investigate the issue. They did not find any undelivered emails from Google Groups. I have contacted Google via their feedback form, but they did not respond. How can I fix this issue or how can I get more info about why the email has undeliverable status?